# XCode: The document: "<document name>" could not be saved. The file has been changed by another application"

Tags: xcode4

Since starting to use XCode 4.2 I've more-or-less routinely had the error:

[image]

with various substitutions for the filename.  This is normally when Xcode is doing an autosave, so it happens seemingly at random.  I generally click "Save Anyway" and my recent edits are then preserved, although there is a significant probability that Xcode will then hang.  I don't typically lose much when it hangs, other than a minute to shoot it and get it to restart, but still...

I *don't* open any of these files in any application except XCode.  I have not been able to figure out the pattern, although it may have to do with popping back and forth between files. The last time I noticed it, I also noticed that the previous round of edits to that file hadn't taken.  So some other editor had not saved the file.

Enough preamble: **here's the question**:

Are others running into this?  Has anyone narrowed down what causes it?  Is there a setting I can change to prevent it? Is there something I can change in my behaviour?

Comment: I have the same problem and literally no idea what's causing it.

Comment: Same here, and unfortunately I also have no answer.

Comment: same here. I have this error when try to localize a xib file.

Comment: Yep, same problem, I'm certain no other program besides XCode is running or modifying files. I do get this when the Storyboard and the Controller file both have unsaved changes.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm using Xcode 5 on Mavericks, and my project is on an NTFS folder. This seems to only happen with one specific .cpp file, but it's happening every few minutes. Annoying!

Comment: I have the same problem. Current version of Xcode: 8.3.3. Even if no changes are made. I press cmd + s, and the error pops up.

Answer (score 2):

You will get this happening when

1) There are locally unsaved modifications (the navigator icon will be shaded)

2) AND something else has changed the file outside of Xcode. For me this occurs when I do an external update from `svn` on the command line or via `Versions`

What do you have that is modifying and saving the file outside of Xcode? Anything?

Check your source control (if any) and figure out if something you are doing is causing the conditions to be met.

Comment: As I said in the original post, nothing is modifying and saving the file outside of XCode.   I don't use a source code control system.

Answer (score 1):

Well I had the same problem when I was trying to Localize my files. Then I noticed that every time the message was popping up was because the icon of the selected file in the Project Navigator was grey, which means that was not saved. So what I did was to save the file (Cmd+S) before doing the action that made the "changed by another application" message to appear, in my case the Localize button.

Comment: I've never localized my application.  I've not updated Xcode recently; perhaps when I do the problem will go away...

Comment: It's not about the Localization. Just check before doing what you do and make the pop up appear if your files are saved or not (grey in Project Navigator)

Comment: As I said "I have not been able to figure out the pattern".  If I knew what the pattern was, I could "check before".

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the meaning of the "figure out the pattern" before that commment.

Comment: The action that makes it pop up for me is saving